# Chrome HTTP2.0 throws SPDY PROTOCOL ERROR

Tags: google-chrome, iis, asp.net-web-api, spdy, http2

I'm using Windows 10 Technical preview. I know it's not yet tweeked out to full usage, but here is my problem.
On local IIS I'm developing my web app. It loads most of the data via ASP.NET MVC API. After the upgrade to Windows 10 I started to get

> net::ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR

for all AJAX calls to API. The HTML page loads normally, but the dynamic loading of data content fails. I managed to figure it out by starting Chrome with parameters

> --use-spdy=off --use-system-ssl

Strange thing is that on the first start I always get this error and have to restart Chrome. Other browsers fail too, but not with specific error. For the transfer there is used HTTP2.0 protocol, which is based on SPDY protocol.

Do I have to turn something off in IIS?

**Edit:**
Seems like an IIS problem with HTTP2.0. When trying to enter the site from Windows 8.1 I get the same error.

Comment: There are several drafts of HTTP/2 besides the final version, which is pretty recent. One possible cause is that your server and client support different drafts and at least one of them doesn't support HTTP/2 final. Also, check the cipher suites that you have enabled in your server, HTTP/2 is picky about which ones are allowed, and they have to go first during the SSL negotiation. Check my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30643058/serving-http-version-of-site-to-those-who-dont-support-http2#answer-30763355) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Most people’s reaction to this error would be to reload the web page. We would actually recommend this as a first response. Sometimes this even does work.

Interesting Factoid: SPDY actually stands for “speedy” and is used to reduce a web pages’ load time

If reloading the web pages does not remove the error, then you should close down Google Chrome and restart it. This alone will not really solve the problem because you will need to clear the cache as soon as you restart the browser.

or in cmd clear dns using this command  ipconfig/flushdns